# Last entry of a history table with MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I developed a database with Access with the next architecture:

First table:

1. Identifier
2. Serial number
3. Revision (Yes/No)

And the second table, linked to the first one by their identifiers, that it's being used like a history, keeping some events with his responsible:

1. Identifier
2. Date event
3. Responsible event
4. Event description

So, I'm trying to make a SQL query that brings me the last event in the history table for a determined identifier by this way:

```
SELECT M.ID, M.SN, Last(H.Date) AS MaxDate, Last(H.Responsible) AS LastResponsible, 
Last(H.Description) AS LastDescription
FROM TABLE1 AS M INNER JOIN History AS H ON M.ID=H.ID
WHERE M.Disponible=No
GROUP BY M.ID, M.SN;
```

But it's bringing to me sometimes values in history that are not the last ones, why could be the reason?

Comment: Have you tried using MAX instead of LAST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first group `History` to find the Max entries. Make a subquery of this, and then JOIN the subquery with `TABLE1`.

See this question for a good example:
[Is it better / more efficient to use sub queries or SELECT statements within the WHERE clause (in MS Access)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424054/is-it-better-more-efficient-to-use-sub-queries-or-select-statements-within-the)
(you want the "combined as a single query" variant).

If you can't get it to work, add a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Andre451, I tried first the suggestion of Darren Bartrup-Cook and it works for me, but I'll read the question later! :)